Keep SQLite db File Current
I’m working on a C# project that will be using a SQLite database. How can I keep the database synced? When I build and run the project, the database file is copied into the bin folder and is accessed from that location. However, when I update the database or upload to GitHub, Visual Studio uses the fie that is in the project folder. Is there a way to keep the db file synced between updates, uploads to GitHub, and builds?

"What is the best way" - Questions are inherently opinion-based and tend to get closed pretty fast. Why not just ask "How to ..." - which is the actual question and any user that thinks they can answer would probably think of their approach to be the "best" anyway.

Also, this sounds really confusing. Maybe rephrase the question to explain what you are trying to accomplish as if we don't know anything about your project, its requirements and your current approach to it.

@Fildor questions edited

What is the actual problem? How to upgrade an existing SQLite file when you make modifications to the source file? That's not something that can be solved with a setting. When you deploy your application the end user can add a lot of data. When you deploy a new version the application should make sure the existing data is maintained. That means it should either make modifications to the old file to match the new schema (that's what migration scripts are for), or copy the old data into the new file.

OK, the edit was a little helpful. I guess you mean that you'll make changes to the database schema that your application is using. And then, Databases that are already in use at the clients' would be incompatible. Well - as Panagiotis already said: usually, you'd have migration scripts. BUT: in the case of SQLite, we have a single-file, local database. So, it's a little bit like an application-fileformat. In which case I'd recommend to keep a version pragma and in-app support for migration or support downward compatibility.

Thanks y’all. My issue wasn’t really for deployment - that’s another ball of wax. No, my issue was when I’m testing, the application was using the file in the bin\debug, not the one in my project folder which I was updating. This also presented issues when I uploaded to GitHub the database had no data as the running application updated the one in bin. The simple solution was to simply reference the project folder when in debug mode. This allows updates to the schema and copies the same db to GitHub.

Ahhh, now it makes sense. Check the properties of the file in Visual Studio. For "copy to output directory", does it have "Copy if newer" or "Never" or something else? Maybe try "copy always".

So the issue with Copy Always is when I’m testing and adding data during program execution, the database file will be written over by a fresh, clean, and empty copy. But the key, at least the way I’m wanting yo use it, is to just make sure the running app (in debug mode) references the db file in the project folder. The Copy Always will def help when publishing at that db will be up to date. Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion.

The simple solution was to simply reference the project folder when in debug mode as opposed to copying the db file to the bin folder. This allows updates to the schema and copies the same db to GitHub.
